# Finding Button with Button Class Using Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on this button.

HTML:

```
<button class="w-full h-14 pt-2 pb-1 px-3 bg-accent text-dark-1 rounded-full md:rounded select-none cursor-pointer md:hover:shadow-big focus:outline-none md:focus:bg-accent-2 md:focus:shadow-small ">
    <div class="font-medium">
        <div class="text-17 md:text-18 md:font-bold leading-18">Ativar</div>
        <div class="text-13 md:text-12 font-normal md:font-medium leading-normal">4 horas Minerando</div>
    </div>
</button>
```

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="4 horas Minerando"]').click()
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What does, "it didn't work", mean? It didn't find the element or some other error message? If so, edit your question and post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your locator didn't work is because

```
//button[text()="4 horas Minerando"]
```

is looking for a button that contain the exact text "4 horas Minerando" directly inside the BUTTON element (not child elements). Google the difference between XPath `text()` and `.` for more info.

There are a number of ways to get around this, here are a couple

```
//button[contains(.,"4 horas Minerando")]
^ find a BUTTON tag
        ^ that contains in *any of the child text*, "4 horas Minerando"

//button[.//div[text()="4 horas Minerando"]]
^ find a BUTTON tag
        ^ that has a descendant DIV that *itself* contains the text, "4 horas Minerando"
```

I tested both and both work on the HTML you have posted. You can choose whichever one you prefer.

---

You may need to add a wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[.//div[text()="4 horas Minerando"]]')).click()
```

Comment: Hello, then would it look like this? 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[.//div[text()="4 horas Minerando"]]').click()`

Comment: is showing this error: 

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[.//div[text()="4 horas Minerando"]]"}`

but on Crtl + F search, when i type:
 `//button[.//div[text()="4 horas Minerando"]] `
he quickly finds the button

Comment: You may need to add a wait. Updated the answer.

Comment: takes a while and the following message appears in red: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[.//div[text()="4 horas Minerando"]]'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: could there be something on the site that was preventing the bot from finding the button?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. All I have to go on is the HTML you posted and I've tested that both of these locators work with it. Short of seeing the page itself, I'm not sure what else I can do. Have you verified that the element is not in an IFRAME?

Comment: sorry, i started learning html last week, but checking here i believe it is an IFRAME. What does that mean?